# What combination of camera, teleconverter, image stacking, or sharpness increase will best improve my moon photographs?

Tags: technique, teleconverter, moon

I'm trying to improve my moon shots.

I'm currently shooting it with a Canon EF100-400mm f/4.5-5.6 USM lens mounted either on a `Canon 450D` or a `Canon 6D`.

I realized that my `Canon 6D` gets me fantastic results but the moon is too small. I can crop nicely but it has its limits.

On the other hand, the 450D gives me less sharp results but the moon is bigger. Of course, I cannot crop much because it's quickly messy.

I've read about teleconverter and the fact they decrease sharpness. Buying a 2x is out of question because of the quality loss but I'm questioning myself on the 1.4x.

More specifically, the question I'm asking myself is :

What would be the better setup to get a nice shot of the moon ?

- Canon 6D, Canon 100-400L, increase sharpness through Lightroom
- Canon 4506D, Canon 100-400L, increase sharpness through Lightroom
- Canon 6D, Canon 100-400L, image stack up
- Canon 450D, Canon 100-400L, image stack up
- Canon 6D, Canon 100-400L, 1.4x teleconverter, increase sharpness through Lightroom
- Canon 450D, Canon 100-400L, 1.4x teleconverter, increase sharpness through Lightroom
- Canon 6D, Canon 100-400L, 1.4x teleconverter, image stack up
- Canon 450D, Canon 100-400L, 1.4x teleconverter, image stack up

Do you guys have experience in that field ? Have you already tried one or more of those combos ? Is there a much better way to improve my shots ?

*P.s. I know shooting the moon with landscape would be better, my whole point here is only to get a moon as big and sharp as possible.*

**Samples (both processed with Lightroom only) :**

Canon 6D : 
[image]
https://500px.com/photo/116560719/madam-by-andy-m?from=user_library

Canon 450D : 
[image]https://500px.com/photo/117058521/orange-madam-by-andy-m?from=user_library

Comment: Air stability is your main concern here. Best practice here is to make raw pictures or a raw movie and process it using astro photography such as DSS (Digital Sky Stacker), RegiStax or (I think this is the best option for novices and moon stakcks): AutoStakkert2. Normally, you'd take 100's of pics and (automatically) merge the best 10 or 20 of them.

Comment: @agtoever I'm already shooting raw. I've tried registax, pipp and autostakkert2. I didn't shoot that much photos tho, 50 at most... I'll try much more next time. Thank you!

Comment: @mattdm yeah I meant that my starting point was at the focal given in parenthesis. It's like, out of the sensor, without cropping, my moon will be bigger with the 450D.

Comment: @mattdm I didn't see it as confusing. I'll remove it.

Comment: Your photos are already quite good.  With any more magnification you are going to need a tracking mount which can cost a pretty penny.

Comment: @Jon they aren't as expensive as people make them out to be.  http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/681852-REG/Celestron_91509_Omni_CG_4_Mount.html - the motors aren't that expensive. Where it gets expensive is if you start doing the "get me a GPS computerized mount that will point and track deep sky objects without me having to do any math."  If you are willing to do the math of "I'm at this location, I need to have the motor track at this many degrees per hour" and have a good equatorial mount tripod, its not expensive at all (compared to the rest of photography).

Comment: [Jon](http://photo.stackexchange.com/users/124/jrista) (I guess it's him) made comparison [in this thread on Canon rumors forum that is comparable to your situation (crop vs FF)](http://www.canonrumors.com/forum/index.php?topic=22161.0) Take a look!

Comment: @null You meant Jrista ? Anyway, super article, thanks a lot for sharing it !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not a moon photographer, but your examples are just about as impressive as I've seen taken with a DSLR and standard camera lens. Some of the things you're looking at may help, but I think they're just going to be incremental. Additional sharpening is only going to get you so much, and the teleconverter is only giving you a less-than-50% increase in each dimension, and stacking can give you more detail but ultimately not something anyone will notice from across the room.

To really take things to the next level — which I think is where you want to go, especially since you mention that you just want moon images, not landscapes-with-moon — I think what you want is a telescope. Mount your camera to that with a "t-ring adapter". See [How do I choose a telescope for space and planets photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/45581/how-do-i-choose-a-telescope-for-space-and-planets-photography) and   [How to shoot images from a home telescope using a digital SLR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18388/how-to-shoot-images-from-a-home-telescope-using-a-digital-slr) for your next steps.

Comment: yeah, a telescope would be awesome, but it's going to cost me a kidney :)

Comment: @AndyM a reasonable telescope and mount is half the price of your 100-400mm lens: http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/617026-REG/Celestron_21094_Omni_XLT_150_R.html .  If you are willing to match the price of your current lens, you can get an even nicer telescope and mount: http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/917578-REG/celestron_22020_advancd_vx_6_refractor.html

Comment: @MichaelT Yeah, I've looked a bit for a Telescope and mount. It's not THAT expensive but, unlike my lens, it will serve me for a single purpose (well, let's say sky photography). So it is a bit of a big invest. I'd be interested in deep sky photography so, the telescope option seems to come more and more interesting :) Thanks for your comment !